# Is it possible to cancel a quest?

Tags: the-secret-world

In The Secret World, is it possible to cancel a quest? Without completing each quest that you pick up the only way that I have found is to select another quest that will 'replace' the quest you're currently on. Without replacing the quest you can move onto the next area but there will consistently be a quest mark on the Agartha entrance until such a time you replace the quest.

So, is it possible to cancel a quest in The Secret World or are the only options to complete/replace the quest?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it's not possible to 'abandon' a quest. You can either complete it or replace it if the arrow bothers you that much.